# Docker gitlab runner cannot find its path with the odoo image

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, odoo-10, gitlab-ci-runner

With the **shell executor** the gitlab runner passes the tests successfully

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.0 (0118d89)
  on Runner01 (02cf77da)
Using Shell executor...
Running on GitlabRunner01...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at c931894 left only attendance view access permissions
Checking out d517f932 as develop9...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ chmod +x tests.sh
$ ./tests.sh
Testing for modules: hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides
Starting tests with the following command: /gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin --addons-path=/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/addons --log-level error -d testdb --init hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides --test-enable --stop-after-init 2>&1 | tee test_results.log
2017-08-04 13:28:17,387 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "mail_followers" ("id", "res_model", "partner_id", "res_id", "channel_id") VALUES(nextval('mail_followers_id_seq'), 'mail.channel', 251, 19, 15) RETURNING id
2017-08-04 13:45:45,905 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,906 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,912 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,915 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,915 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,916 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,916 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,917 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:45,918 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,039 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,040 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,040 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,040 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,040 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,041 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,041 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:48,041 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:49,003 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:49,004 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
2017-08-04 13:45:49,691 8280 INFO testdb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "slide_channel" SET "promoted_slide_id"=1,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (1)
Tests Finished
Failure in tests: 
Cleaning up
Deleting Databse
Database Deleted
Removing log file
Log file deleted
Clean up finished
PASSED
Job succeeded
```

But when i am executing with the docker containing **odoo** image then why the **gitlab-runner** path is not specified and the issue about the **postgres**.
As with the same configurations the above shell executor and the same path is executed.
The log with the **Docker executor** :

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.2 (6d06f2e)
  on docker (9db168e2)
Using Docker executor with image odoo:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:b9394e421b2cf440eb0607e38d93d2a1446f2d5057cb51e736aee4f49da81876 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image odoo:latest ...
Using docker image odoo:latest ID=sha256:15653094bc523040ab938c0712d7a76273c06faf51a7e06a5baf40ef8a132bbc for build container...
Running on runner-9db168e2-project-80-concurrent-0 via ujjwal-All-Series...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 5125285 rm
Checking out 51252859 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
$ ./tests.sh
Testing for modules: hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides
Starting tests with the following command: /gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin --addons-path=/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/addons --log-level error -d testdb --init hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides --test-enable --stop-after-init 2>&1 | tee test_results.log
./tests.sh: line 11: /gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin: No such file or directory
Tests Finished
Failure in tests: 
Cleaning up
Deleting Databse
dropdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Database Deleted
Removing log file
Log file deleted
Clean up finished
PASSED
Job succeeded
```

> My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like:

```
before_script:
  - python -V

test:
  script:
  - ./tests.sh
```

> Script file tests.sh looks like-

```
ADDONS_DIR="./addons"
DELETE_DB="dropdb testdb"


MODULE_LIST="hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides"
echo "Testing for modules: $MODULE_LIST"


RUN_ODOO="/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin --addons-path=/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/addons --log-level error -d testdb --init $MODULE_LIST --test-enable --stop-after-init 2>&1 | tee test_results.log"
echo "Starting tests with the following command: $RUN_ODOO"
eval $RUN_ODOO
echo "Tests Finished"

RESULT=$(grep "FAIL\|ERROR" test_results.log)

echo "Failure in tests: $RESULT"

echo "Cleaning up"

echo "Deleting Databse"
eval $DELETE_DB
echo "Database Deleted"

echo "Removing log file"
rm test_results.log
echo "Log file deleted"

echo "Clean up finished"


if [ ! -z "$RESULT" ] 
  then
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "PASSED"
    exit 0
fi
```

I just cannot understand the difference as it should also run with the docker executor.
Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: You have Postgres installed on the host machine?

Comment: Yes, postgres is installed

Comment: How and where are you executing this DB connection?

Comment: In this ques i've added 2 files, see if you can get anything from here as i am new in this.

Comment: You are executing inside Docker container which will not have the files from your hosts. That is why you are seeing the error "/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin" No such file or directory. If you are using a docker runner then you need to specify a image which has these executables and not use anything from host

Comment: ok i got it, but can you please tell me how to **specify the image** instead of _"/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin"_ to execute it ?